# add span tag within anchor in jquery

Tags: jquery

How to add span tag within anchor, changing it from

```
<a href="somewhere.html">Here is the link to somewhere.</a>
```

to this with jquery

```
<a href="somewhere.html">
<span>Here is the span content.</span>
Here is the link to somewhere.
</a>
```

Comment: Look up html() function in jQuery docs and use it to change anchor content.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('a').each(function() {
     $(this).prepend('<span>This is the span content</span>');
});
```

This will add a span tag to the start of each and every `a` element on the page. If you want to restrict the modifying to some specific elements, add a class to them and call them with something like `$('a.myclass').each(...`

Comment: @marcgg, you are mistaken, please check the documentation for `prepend` in the manual before downvoting.

Comment: yes my bad I realized seconds before your comment. I removed my downvote right away

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this will work:

```
$('a').each(function()
{
  $(this).wrapInner("<span></span>");
});
```

[JQuery docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/wrapInner#html)

Answer (score 2):

Add a way to select the link :

```
<a id="myLink" href="somewhere.html">Here is the link to somewhere.</a>
```

The do some jQuery :

```
var $link = jQuery("#myLink");
$link.html( "<span>blah</span>" + $link.html() );
```

An even cooler way of doing this would be using [prepend](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/prepend) :

```
jQuery("#myLink").prepend("<span>blah</span>");
```