# How to add a span inside a link tag with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink, anchor

I have this code here in HTML:

```
<a class="cta" href="URL" target="_blank">TEXT</a>
```

What I try to achieve is to add a `span` tag inside the link tag, so that it would look like this:

```
<a class="cta" href="URL" target=_"blank"><span>TEXT</span></a>
```

I tried with prepend but it seems not to work for my case…

Comment: $(".cta").html("<span">+$(".cta").html()+"</span>");

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013710/add-span-tag-within-anchor-in-jquery since the correct solution to that question's problem was `.prepend()`, while here it is `.wrapInner()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`.html( function )`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) is a good method for changing html content of element. Current html content of element setted in `html` variable in function that you can set it in new added child.

```js
$("a.cta").html(function(i, html){
  return "<span>"+ html +"</span>";
});
```

```css
span { color: red }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="cta" href="URL" target="_blank">TEXT</a>
<a class="cta" href="URL" target="_blank">TEXT 2</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for the very fast reply and for the example I think that's the best solution for my case! Thank you Mohammad!

Comment: @cbtr I'm not exactly sure why you consider this a better solution than the tailor-made `$.wrapInner()` method which is designed for exactly what you have asked.

Answer (score 3):

Using jQuery's [`.wrapInner( wrappingElement )`](https://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/):

```
$(".cta" ).wrapInner("<span></span>");
```

> **Description:** Wrap an HTML structure around the content of each element in the set of matched elements.
>
> The `.wrapInner()` function can take any string or object that could be passed to the `$()` factory function to specify a DOM structure. This structure may be nested several levels deep, but should contain only one inmost element. The structure will be wrapped around the content of each of the elements in the set of matched elements.
>
> Source: https://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/

Comment: Thank you Connexo, I didn't know this method at all!

Comment: No problem, I didn't know it either. Looks like this is the method specifically tailored for your use case.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.wrapInner()` in jquery

> Description: Wrap an HTML structure around the content of each element
>   in the set of matched elements.

```
 var con = $('.cta').text();
 $(".cta").empty().wrapInner("<span>"+con+"</span>");
```

http://api.jquery.com/wrapinner/

Comment: I didn't know about wrapInner method, interesting, but the problem with that method, is that you need to manually declare the inside of the span tag, might be a solution if the content is rather in a variable. Anyway thank you!

Comment: Interesting way, as well, all methods listed above or below worked perfectly!

Comment: Putting the content between the `span` tags explicitly is exactly what is unnecessary with `.wrapInner()` method.

Comment: @connexo - That's  why My answer does not accepted by the Question Owner.

Comment: Also, this question is not a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013710/add-span-tag-within-anchor-in-jquery since the correct solution to that question was `.prepend()`, while here it is `.wrapInner()`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the content first and then replace the current to another that you made!
You can use a classe selector like `$(".myClass")` then replace the text by using the `$(".myClass").html("<p>My new HTML content</p>");` method on the selected target:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".cta").html("<span>" + $(".cta").html() + "</span>");
});
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/418/) to see this in action

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
$('a.cta').each(function(){
var text = $(this).text();//take the text from the link
$(this).html($('<span>',{text:text}));//create a span tag and append the text in it after that use html to append the span to the link tag
});
```

```js
$('a.cta').each(function(){
var text = $(this).text();//take the text from the link
$(this).html($('<span>',{text:text}));//create a span tag and append the text in it after that use html to append the span to the link tag
})
```

```css
span { color: red }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="cta" href="URL" target="_blank">TEXT</a>
<a class="cta" href="URL" target="_blank">TEXT2</a>
<a class="cta" href="URL" target="_blank">TEXT3</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `html()`:

```
$(function() {
   $('.cta').html( '<span>'+$('.cta').html()+</span>' );
});
```