# Javascript code for Bootstrap Sidebar menu not working

Tags: javascript, django

I have a `Sidebar / Menu` that I am working with. It has been created with `Bootstrap`, `DJango`, and `Javascript`.

Basically, I am trying to write Javascript so that when on clicks on a menu-item, the background changes color (dark blue), the icon change color (light green / turquoise) and it gets a type of "wedge"

Below is an example of a menu-item that has been chosen (Dashboard) along with menu-items that have not been chosen (Security and Messages). The "wedge" has a red arrow pointing to it.

[image]

**Here is the HTML code that is being used:**

```
[... snip ...]

   <div class="page-container">

        <div class="page-sidebar-wrapper">

            <div class="page-sidebar navbar-collapse collapse">

                <ul class="page-sidebar-menu  page-header-fixed page-sidebar-menu-hover-submenu " 
                    data-keep-expanded="false" data-auto-scroll="true" data-slide-speed="200">
                    <li class="nav-item start active open">
                        <a href="{% url 'mainadmin:dashboard'  %}" class="nav-link nav-toggle">
                            <i class="fa fa-tachometer"></i>
                            <span class="title">Dashboard</span>
                            <span class="selected"></span>
                            <span class="arrow open"></span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item  ">
                        <a href="{% url 'mainadmin:security'  %}" class="nav-link nav-toggle">
                            <i class="fa fa-users"></i>
                            <span class="title">Security</span>
                            <span class="arrow"></span>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                     <li class="nav-item  ">
                        <a href="{% url 'mainadmin:in_progress' %}" class="nav-link nav-toggle">
                            <i class="fa fa-comment"></i>
                            <span class="title">Messages</span>
                            <span class="arrow"></span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                            <li class="nav-item  ">
                                <a href="{% url 'mainadmin:in_progress' %}" class="nav-link ">
                                    <span class="title">List All Messages</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item  ">
                                <a href="{% url 'mainadmin:in_progress' %}" class="nav-link ">
                                    <span class="title">List My Messages</span>
                                    <span class="badge badge-danger"></span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

[... snip ...]
```

**Here is the Javascript code:**

```
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('.nav-item a').click(function(e) {

                $('.nav-item a').removeClass('selected');
                $('.nav-item a').removeClass('arrow');
                $('.nav-item a').removeClass('open');
                $('.nav-item a').removeClass('active');

        alert("I have gotten in");

                var $parent = $(this).parent();
                $parent.addClass('selected');
                $parent.addClass('arrow');
                $parent.addClass('open');
                $parent.addClass('active');


                e.preventDefault();
                });
            });

        </script>
```

I do get the alert message - but - what happens is :

- -> the background of the chosen menu-item does change color - which is correct
- --> The icon of the chosen menu-item changes color (to light blue / turquoise) - which is correct
- -> the tick of the arrow does not take place for the chosen menu-item :(
- -> the old chosen menu item does not  "de-select"

What am I doing wrong?

TIA

Hi @Joe Lissner

Thanks so much for the response!

I had to add the following to get the "wedge" portion to work. It required span tags

```
// REFERENCE: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013710/add-span-tag-within-anchor-in-jquery

$(this).append('<span class="selected"></span>');

$(this).append('<span class="arrow open"></span>');
```

While this works when clicking on the main-menu item, I'm not so lucky when it comes to clicking on sub-menu items. As of now, I am pretty much new to Javascript.

How would one get the sub-menu items to work?

Also, when clicking on an item, it does not go to the page specified in "href="
How would can one make changes to the code so that when the menu-item is clicked, it would go to the page specified in "href="

Again, thanks for the response :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are removing the classes from the `a` tags, not the `.nav-item` elements.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.nav-item a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // best practice to have this first, if you remove this line then the link will function as expected.

        var $parent = $(this).parent();
        var $arrow = $parent.find('.arrow');

        $('.nav-item').removeClass('selected arrow open active'); // simplified
        $('.nav-item .arrow').removeClass('open');
        $('.nav-item .selected').detach(); // remove the span that was there before

        alert("I have gotten in");

        $parent.addClass('open active'); // simplified
        $arrow.addClass('open').before('<span class="selected" />')
    });
});
```

**Edit** - Fixed the issue with the arrow

Comment: Hi @Joe Lissner - thanks for the response! I made some updates above. Can you look?

Comment: Hi Joe, I got the arrow issue fixed (see in the notes) - I just used the "append". Just trying to get it to work with the sub-menus now and to fix it so that when clicking the button, it goes to the page mentioned in "href"

Comment: I fixed the issue so that the arrow now moves properly, but the issue of the page not changing has to do with how this is happening. The first line on the click event is `e.preventDefault()` which is basically saying *Don't do what you normally do*. What a link normally does, is goes to a page. If you want it to go to the page, then all of the other stuff here doesn't matter cause a new page will be loading. You should look into changing your code to either dynamically load the page or fire the javascript on the correct link on page load

Comment: Hi @Joe Lissner - thanks for the input! If I fire the Javascript on the page load, could I salvage any of the work above?

Comment: Definitely! You would just need to figure out with element should be the active one (from info sent from the server would be best, but you could parse the url if needed) and just make the `$parent` variable equal that element, then just evoke on load instead of on click.

Comment: @OK Joe Lissner - will do some more research in that area. Thanks again for the help!